# Class not found when using provided hibernate-core

Tags: maven, jboss-eap-6

Currently trying to build deploy an application on Jboss EAP 6.4 but getting the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/Session;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.initMembers(Component.java:560) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.<init>(Component.java:244) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.<init>(Component.java:205) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.addComponent(Initialization.java:1255) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        ... 21 more
```

I have the following dependency which I thought would use the hibernate that is built into the jboss modules. Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.Final-redhat-2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a module dependency to a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` or in your `MANIFEST.MF`?

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

- Change the scope to **compile** so that maven add the hibernate libs in your application's classpath;
- Add a **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** file in your WEB-INF folder with the **org.hibernate** module dependecy included, like this:

  `<jboss-deployment-structure>
     <deployment>
        <dependencies>
           <module name="org.hibernate" />
        </dependencies>
     </deployment>
  </jboss-deployment-structure>`
- In your pom file, add the following plugin with this configuration so that maven adds the above dependency in the MANIFEST.MF file:

  `<plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <archive>
              <manifestEntries>
                 <Dependencies>org.hibernate</Dependencies>
              </manifestEntries>
           </archive>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>`